# How to delete all the duplicate observations but add a column with the frequency in SAS?

Tags: sas

In a dataset in SAS, I have some observations multiple times. What I am trying to do is: I am trying to add a column with the frequency of each observation and make sure I keep it only one time in my dataset. I have to do this for a dataset with many rows and around 8 variables.

```
name     id     address    age
jack     2      chicago     50
peter    4      new york    45
jack     2      chicago     50
```

This would have to become:

```
name     id     address    age     frequency
jack     2       chicago    50        2
peter    4      new york    45        1
```

Is there anybody who knows how to do this in SAS (preferably without using SQL)?
Thank you a lot!

Comment: Hm, why do you not want to use SQL? you would just have to use distinct and a count, that would be very simple. For a datastep solution i would spontaneous think of using a proc freq statement and merge with the original data set.

Comment: Its for a course in which we are not supposed to use SQL. Okay I will try it like that, thank you :)

Comment: Hm, i guess proc summary is what you are looking for, you should google it...

Comment: Sort and use last. Logic as well is an option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@kl78 is right, `proc summary` is the best non-sql solution here.  This runs in memory which can cause problems with very large datasets, but you should be ok with 8 columns.

`class _all_` will group by all the variables and the frequency is output by default, so there's no need to specify any measures.  I've dropped the other automatic variable, `_type_`, as it isn't relevant here and renamed `_freq_`.

```
data have;
input name $ id address &$ age;
datalines;
jack     2      chicago     50
peter    4      new york    45
jack     2      chicago     50
;
run;

proc summary data=have nway;
class _all_;
output out=want (drop=_type_ rename=(_freq_=frequency));
run;
```